# Is there any new published book that is written in latin?

Tags: new-latin, book

I wondered that is there any new book that is written in latin publishing now ?

Like new latin books in 21st century. If so what is the difference of new published books from the literature of classical authors.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, precisely one crapload. There is a large number of Latin "novellas" as they're called which are typically written by bored Latin teachers with too much time on their hands for their students. They are usually levelled for different levels of proficiency.
On the other hand, there are a bunch of translations of modern books into classical Latin, including *Winnie ille Pu, Hobbitus Ille, Harrius Potter et Philosophiae Lapis,* and some others.

The major difference I've noticed is that Classical authors were writing about their own times in their own language. Many of these new Latin novellas cover classical contents like mythology or family life, but are often seen through a lens of our own modern culture. So there might be commentary on topics like slavery, military conquest and genocide with our modern preconceptions attached.

So if you want to read *new* content, which is *almost* always written for classroom use, they are worth checking out.

A word of advice though, *Winnie ille Pu* is **brutal,** it is not an easy read by any stretch of the imagination.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a list I started to compile, most of which can be found at [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com.br/Winnie-Latin-Translation-Milnes-Winnie/dp/4871873943/ref=sr_1_2?__mk_pt_BR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=2MJ3RHHTNL3B4&dchild=1&keywords=winnie%20ille%20pu&qid=1600960102&sprefix=winnie%20ill%2Cstripbooks%2C220&sr=8-2):

- Harrius Potter et Philosophi Lapis (Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone)
- Harrius Potter et Camera Secretorum (Harry Potter and the Clhamber of Secrets)
- Hobbitus Ille (The Hobbit)
- Cattus Petasatus (The Cat in the Hat)
- Winnie Ille Pu (Winnie the Pooh)
- Familia Mala: Saturnus et Iuppiter
- Duo Fratres: Familia Mala Vol. 2
- Pandora: Familia Mala Volumen III
- Ego, Polyphemus
- Labyrinthus
- Via Periculosa
- Ira Veneris
- Vox in Tenebris
- Alicia in Terra Mirabili (Alice in Wonderland)
- Aliciae Per Speculum Transitus (Through The Looking Glass)
- Quomodo Invidiosulus Nomine Grinchus Christi Natalem Abrogaverit (How the Grinch Stole Christmas)
- Tela Charlottae (Charlotte's Web)
- Olivia
- Ferdinandus Taurus (Ferdinand the Bull)
- Ubi Fera Sunt (Where the Wild Things Are)
- Arbor Alma (The Giving Tree)
- Fabula de Petro Cuniculo (The Fable of Peter Rabbit)
- Regulus (The Little Prince)
- Avem occidere mimicam (To Kill a Mockingbird)
- De Corde & Mente (Sense and Sensibility)
- Superbia et Odium (Pride and Prejudice)
- Magus Mirabilis in Oz (The Wizard of Oz)
- Ursus Nomine Paddington (A Bear Called Paddington)
- Tres Viri in Scapha (Three Men in a Boat)
- Fabellae (Tales of Washington Irving)
- Pericla Navarchi Magonis (The Adventures of Captain Mago)
- Dominus Quixotus a Manica (Don Quixote)
- Vere, Virginia, Sanctus Nicolaus Est! (Yes, Virginia, There Is a Santa Claus)
- Rebilius Cruso (Robinson Crusoe)
- Carmen ad Festum Nativitatis (A Christmas Carol)
- Virent Ova! Viret Perna!! (Green Eggs and Ham)
- Aurae Inter Salices (The Wind In The Willows)
- Fundus Animalium (Animal Farm)
- Fabula de Beniamine Lago (The Tale of Benjamin Bunny)
- Insula Thesauraria (Treasure Island)
- Hospes Draculae (Dracula's Guest)
- Pericla Thomae Sawyer (The Adventures of Tom Sawyer)
- Fabulae Divales (Fairy Tales)
- Captivus Zendae (The Prisoner of Zenda)

In addition to these, Wikipedia also has a list of many others: [List of Latin translations of modern literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Latin_translations_of_modern_literature)

Comment: A translation of *To kill a mockingbird* was also recently published (*Avem occidere mimicam*) but seems not to have made it onto the Wikipedia list, unless I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new adventure novel in Latin you can find on Amazon: Centurio Aelius Valerius: Pericula Sub Sole